# Delete github folder, rename the next folder without changing anything else

Tags: git, github

Good morning! (Depends where you live)

I'd like to do something without deleting my previous commits and without having any problems. I tried some stuff before but they didnt work for some reason. One of them was to try to change the folder names through github but I couldn't.

Let's say that I have a repository called Garbage. This repository contains a project with many versions, which you can only see when you press the commits. So I don't have a different folder for every version. What I did wrong is that when I made it I named my folder GarbageV3 that contains my repo, and then for some reason I have another empty folder called GarbageV3 which is empty. I am submitting an image.

How can I delete one of these folders, rename the folder that contains my project (to make the title generic) without having any conflicts? Because then there won't be any repository since I am going to delete the paths, right? And it's a college project so I don't want to lose the previous versions.

[image]

Comment: Can you show more of your tree structure? Running `tree` or `ls -R` if that doesn't get too long. I'm having trouble identifying the exact problem. From the root of the repository, wouldn't this work? → `git mv GarbageV3/GarbageV3 temp; rmdir GarbageV3; git mv temp GarbageV3; git commit`?

Answer (score 0):

**Make a backup first!!** (e.g. zip or copy your existing local folder).

---

If you want to promote a single directory to the new "root" of your repository, [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) can be used with its [subdirectory](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#Documentation/git-filter-branch.txt---subdirectory-filterltdirectorygt) filter:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter GarbageV3/GarbageV3
```

**All other top-level directories and files will be gone after this operation!** I'm assuming here that running `ls -A` in your top-level *only* shows `GarbageV3/` and running it inside that directory shows only `GarbageV3/` too.

Another option is [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo): `git filter-repo --subdirectory-filter GarbageV3/GarbageV3` (find more examples at https://www.mankier.com/1/git-filter-repo#Examples-Directory_based_shortcuts)